# R msm package freezing

Tags: r, markov-chains

I've been trying to use the msm package to model an 8 state, multi-state markov chain. My data set, in total, contains about 11,000 subjects, with slightly over 100k observations total.

I try to run the msm function on several subsets of the data, taking the head of the data, like so:

```
mm2myTrajectoryMSM<-msm(role ~ year, subject=authId, data=head(mm2myMarkovRoles[,1:3,with=FALSE],7000), qmatrix=trajectory.qmatrix,death=1,control=list(trace=1,REPORT=1))
```

So far, I have not been able to get past ~7000 lines. Looking at the report output, I noticed that the function freezes when the iter value outputs a negative value. For example, here is the run with the first 10k rows of the data

```
initial  value 19017.328402  
iter   2 value 17808.111677 
iter   3 value 17707.483305 
iter   4 value -346782.085429 (freeze)
```

But it works with the first 20k rows

```
initial  value 38101.266287  
iter   2 value 35871.849676 
iter   3 value 35796.410415 
iter   4 value -721867.559664 
iter   4 value -721867.559664 
final  value -721867.559664  
converged
```

But not with 50k rows

```
initial  value 92846.642840 
iter   2 value 88466.007605
iter   3 value 88310.215979
iter   4 value 88276.433502
iter   5 value 88247.381022
iter   6 value -983685.709474
```

But it works for 60010,80007 (I'm capturing full records of subjects), and after that I cannot tell if the system freezes or the analysis is taking a very long time. The 1 cpu assigned to the task is maxed, but I am nowhere near my RAM resources limits (< 1% of the 96GB on the server).

I have two questions - ) Why does the function (arbitrarily?) hang on certain subsets of the data and
2) How can I estimate the run time of this function? Last time I let it run, and it went for over 2 days. Oddly, the computation time for many of the runs appeared to scale sub-linearly, but once I crossed a threshold it scales...?

Comment: Interestingly enough, I ran this same process on an Amazon EC2 server and got a response in < 1 minute on the full data set. I am not sure why this is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you running msm 1.5?

In the changelog (http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/msm/ChangeLog) it is mentioned that a bug has been fixed that led to infinite loops on windows.

If your time-series has several short jumps you might get a log-likelihood underflow. You can study this using `fixedpars = TRUE` in the msm call (then get the log-likelihood and look for underflow/overflow). 
If something is wrong you'll get very long running times (hard to predict).

Also try to scale your likelihood values using `fnscale=100000`.

Comment: Updating the package to 1.5 worked, although I was not running a Windows box (Ubunu 14.04)